# $\gcd(a',b')=1\implies c=ka',d=kb'$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

If we know that $cb'=da'$ and if we know that $\gcd(a',b')=1$ then show that $c=ka'$ and $d=kd'$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

**My attempt** : since $\gcd(a'b')=1\implies a'u+b'v=1$ by multiplying by $c$ we get that $a'cu+b'cv=c$. Which indcates that that $a'$ divides $c$. Is this a valid proof for $c=ka'$?

Comment: You still need to show $d = kb'$ for the same $k = cu + dv$. But that part is easy.

Comment: Does this indicate that my proof is so far valid? I still do not know how $cb'=da'$ would be implemented in the proof.

Comment: Yes. To show that $a'$ divides $c$, you used $cb'=da'$. You will use that again in the second part.

Comment: If you wish to write your comments as an answer it would be better so that I mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $a'cu + b'cv = c$ and $cb'=da'$ we have

$$c = a'cu+da'v = a'(cu+dv)$$

so we can take $k = cu+dv$.

It remains to show that $d=kb'$.

This is trivial since

$$kb'=b'cu+b'dv=da'u+db'v=d(a'u+b'v)=d$$